# Reformatting Dates By using Java

Tags: java, date

**This is the question i got in an online interview test**

[image: Date formatting interview question]

[image: input format]
Output format is like

20th Oct 2052 converts to 2052-10-20.

6th Jun 1933 converts to 1933-06-06.

[image: output format]

> Can any one please write a method to return an array of strings where each index i contains the value of dates converted to the format YYYY-MM-DD.

This is the code to Convert 1st March 1984 to 1984-03-01 By using Java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormattingTest {

 public void date(String dateString) throws ParseException {

  // This Regular Expression will replace st to blank
  String dateString1 = dateString.replaceFirst("[a-zA-Z]{2}", "");
  //create Date Format and Parse it based on input

  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
  Date rightNow = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString1);

  // Now create Date format for output type. and format the input
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(rightNow);
  System.out.println(formattedDate);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
  String dateString = "1st March 1984";
  DateFormattingTest t = new DateFormattingTest();
  t.date(dateString);
 }
}
```

In the above code  input is hard coded  `String dateString = "1st March 1984";`
it gives the correct output

> But according to the question input should be array of strings in the form of  Day Month Year and out put should return an array of strings in the format YYYY-MM-DD. I wrote the dates() method similar to the date() method in the above code. in the solution main method handling IOException it is pre written main method we are supposed to pass our method in main method to return the output but here my method is handling ParseException which is not handled by main method in the given program so i am getting  ParseException handling error so is there any other way of writing function to give the output

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing (with a full error message and stack trace where appropriate), and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.

Comment: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` in 2017. It’s notoriously troublesome, and both it and `Date` are long outdated. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

`"d MMMM yyyy"` requires month in local language, try to set SimpleDateFormat's Locale to English. Also, theres no need to delete "st", try `"d'st' MMMM yyyy`"